# SharePoint Search service restoration from Production to DR environment

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, enterprise-search

We are running a large SharePoint search service application with 11 Million items in search index.

We are having DR servers setup and can not run the search service crawling on content databases in DR database server as the DR content databases are in read only mode with LOG Shipping enabled.

We are afraid as search service index growing on daily basis and could not have any backup at DR environment.

How we can manage the search service available in DR server along with production search instance or at least can we schedule any monthly backup and restoration of search service from production to DR?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired architecture is not supported by Microsoft. There is a technical requirement to keep a sync between databases and the index. This sync cannot be built "externally".

[Taking a copy of the Search Administration database and using it to re-create the Search service application is supported.](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj841106(v=office.15).aspx#SAppDBsSPALL) This will include a time consuming full crawl after switching to DR site ([Crawl the content source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/sharepoint-server-2013-disaster-recovery-in-microsoft-azure))

Comment: how we can recreate the search service in DR with copy of search administration database from production. could you please elaborate?

Comment: we dont need search service active in DR server simultaneously with production. We are planning to back up the production search service application on a monthly basis and restore it on the DR environment. Will it be supported and do we need re crawling the data again in DR server post restoration?  thanks

Comment: You can restore Search with the Restore-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication CMDlet (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/restore-spenterprisesearchserviceapplication?view=sharepoint-ps -> see Example 1). You have to crawl content after restore.

Comment: thanks for your help. I checked the url [link]( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/restore-spenterprisesearchserviceapplication?view=sharepoint-ps) and bit confused. there are no specifications mentioned for the backup folder like index backup or search service backup path in powershell commands. please clarify

Comment: You can find more information on the restore process in this article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719(v=office.16).aspx#Anchor_7. The article is about migration, but it also works with a move in the same version.